# Move an object with a list of points from a text file

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, format, formatexception

I am trying to move my Cube from point to point where the coordinates are from a text file.

```
public class cube : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Speed
    public float speed = 3.0f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
       print("cube says hi");

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        string path = "Assets/Ressources/test.txt";
        var sr = new StreamReader(path);
        List<string> columnx = new List<string>();
        List<string> columny = new List<string>();
        List<string> columnz = new List<string>();

        using (sr)
        {
            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                string line = sr.ReadLine();
                var values = line.Split(new string[] { "      " }, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                columnx.Add(values[0]);
                columny.Add(values[1]);
                columnz.Add(values[2]);

            }


        }


        float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position,
                                            new Vector3(
                                                Convert.ToSingle("1.45", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), Convert.ToSingle("3.258", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), Convert.ToSingle("4.256", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                                            ), step);

    }

}
```

this works, but the problem is when I replace "1.45" "3.25" and  "4.25" by columnx[0] columny[0] and columnz[0] I got

```
FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
System.Number.ParseSingle (System.String value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles options, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo numfmt) (at <437ba245d8404784b9fbab9b439ac908>:0)
```

I wanted to test with the first element so I can make a for loop but it's not even working with 0..

Comment: Try to use `Debug.LogError("'" + columnx[0] "'")`before `transform.position = ...` to see more exactly what is inside the array.

Comment: I got     0.10340200'
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
cube:Update() (at Assets/Scenes/cube.cs:52), which is the first value of my columnx

Comment: Is the single quote `'` after the number part of the array or part of the LogError format ?

Comment: Sorry I pasted wrong, it's  '     0.10340200' (there is 5 spaces before) I dont know why I still got some space... My text file looks like this
     0.10340200      0.01262700      0.46301100
(but there is many different blank size between lines and columns... is it the reason?

Comment: Well each line is expecting an exact number of spaces between the numbers so chances are it could be seeing some parts as one item.

Comment: post you text file somewhere we could dowload it or show it..that will be easier to analyse and you'll will have a solution quickly

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem ! I just put one blank space for split instead of 5 or 6 (which because depends if theres a - or not)... I printed my columns, they are all working ! thanks for that !
But now I am trying to move my object from vector to vector with a for loop :

```
 for (int i =0; i< columnx.Count ; i++)
        {

            position = new Vector3(Convert.ToSingle(columnx[i], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), Convert.ToSingle(columny[i], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), Convert.ToSingle(columnz[i], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));


            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(currentPosition, position, step);


        }
```

but looks like the cube is instantly going at the last point

Comment: This is because your for loop gets executed in a very short amount of time (much less than 1 frame). This could be a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have a file like this with tab, space between number

```
        0.10340200    0.01262700   0.46301100



    0.10340200        0.01262700 0.46301100        
        0.10340200 0.01262700 0.46301100
```

---

i suggest you to use a List of Vector3 directly and to Convert to Float and not single, because Vector3 is a vector of 3 float, so if you convert to single, another conversion is done again (and you loose precision)..

```
    List<Vector3> vec = new List<Vector3>();

    string path = "Assets/file.txt";

    var fileLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path);
    foreach (var line in fileLines)
    {
        var result = line.Split(new char[] { '\t', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        if (result.Length == 3)
        {
            var x = float.Parse(result[0], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            var y = float.Parse(result[1], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            var z = float.Parse(result[2], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            vec.Add(new Vector3(x, y, z));
        }

    }

    float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position,
                                        vec[0], step);
```

Comment: The console prints : 
ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
at the transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position line

Comment: i have no error,   so are you sure to have data in vec list? add Debug.Log(vec.Length). I dont see why you have error..so if your solution is ok..no problem to investigate more

Comment: When I print the data, it makes the same error, and my file is like what you've shown, there's no tabulation, just spaces, but i dont think thats the problem